# Spring Junit Configuration class not loaded

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm writing a junit test where I need to Autowire a specific implementation of an interface. I'm using the @Mock annotation to Autowire the implementation.
I'm using profiles and a Configuration file to determine which implementation to Autowire.
When running the test class  EmailTest , the following error message appears on the console:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register mock bean .... expected a single matching bean to replace but found [customerEmailSender, emailSenderImpl_1, emailSenderImpl_2]

The reason is that the Spring doesn't find or use the config class :  BeanConfiguration.
I know this because I put a breakpoint in the class BeanConfiguration, and the application doesn't break.

What could be the raeson that Spring doesn't find or use the configuration class BeanConfiguration.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test-unit"})
@Import(BeanConfiguration.class)
public class EmailTest {

    @MockBean
    private CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSender;
    
}



@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {


    @Profile({"test-unit"})
    @Bean(name = "customerEmailSender")
    public CustomerEmailSender emailSenderImpl_1(){
        return new EmailSenderImpl_1();
    }

    @Profile({"prd"})
    @Bean(name = "customerEmailSender")
    public CustomerEmailSender emailSenderImpl_2(){
        return new EmailSenderImpl_2();
    }

}
```

Comment: Make BeanConfiguration class inner static class of EmailTest.
Add @ContextConfiguration(classes= BeanConfiguration.class) annotation to EmailTest.

Answer (score 0):

Check if BeanConfiguration package is till in spring's component scan boundary

Comment: I've added  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xx.xx.xx"}) , but that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@MockBean` does not know which bean to replace (and you have multiple beans of the same interface).

Try

```
@MockBean(name = "customerEmailSender")
private CustomerEmailSender customerEmailSender;
```

Comment: That didn't help... still same eror message.

Comment: I just saw that in the `@Configuration` class both beans have the same name. What if you change one of them? Or try `@MockBean(name = "emailSenderImpl_1")`

Comment: The configuration file work fine without junit.  So, there is nothing wrong with the config class

Comment: What I found out is that autowiring via the Mock annotation behaves differently as when to use the plain Autowire annotation.  I'll ask this question in a new Thread.